# How to loop through JSON per group

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and started having trouble with JSON.

I have a object like so:

```
var users =  [
  { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
  { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
  { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
```

Is there anyway I can do a jQuery `$.each` selector to do something with each pair without knowing how many indexes there are?

Like so:

```
$.each(obj.firstname) {
  // Do stuff for John then Anna then Peter
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, btw, it's just a normal JavaScript data structure used in a normal JavaScript script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic usage:

```
$.each(users, function(i, user) {
    var firstName = user.firstName;
    var lastName = user.lastName;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: alert(users[0].firstname); //works                             $.each(users, function(i, obj) {
            alert(users.firstName);//gives undefined
         });

Comment: sorry cant get it to space properly

Comment: @user1752451 The problem is that you use incorrect variables. Just copy the solution which is illustrated in the answer, and it will work.

Answer (score 6):

More like:

```
$.each(users, function(i, data)) {
   console.log(data.firstName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$.each(users,function(key,val){
 $.each(val, function(k, v){alert(k+" - "+v);});
});​
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/xDxHF/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var key in users){
console.log(users[key].firstName)
}
```

Comment: You will want to wrap the loop body with a `hasOwnProperty` call, see [JSLint documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#forin).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at underscore.js, especially the [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) method:

```
_.each(_.pluck(users, 'firstName'), function (firstName) {
    // Do stuff
})
```